# Removing frames from a video - how to make playback not pause during removed frames (i.e. assign new timestamps)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor

I am working off this answer [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/22159/how-to-extract-only-frames-from-videos-that-have-certain-levels-of-luminosity). I have calibrated my video such that the following code perfectly exports the frames I want to keep

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "blackframe=amount=0:threshold=92, metadata=select:key='lavfi.blackframe.pblack':value=45:function=less" -vsync 0  img%d.jpg
```

I modified the code slightly to export to a video

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "blackframe=amount=0:threshold=92, metadata=select:key='lavfi.blackframe.pblack':value=45:function=less" -vsync 0  outz.mp4
```

The problem that I face is the output video is the same length as the input. The correct frames are being dropped but I am guessing the timestamp is not being adjusted because the video appears to pause (shows last non dropped frame) during a playback of removed frames.

I guess I could output the image files to another video editor and recompile into a video but I'd like to do this all within ffmpeg if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to retime remaining frames using setpts.

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "blackframe=amount=0:threshold=92, metadata=select:key='lavfi.blackframe.pblack':value=45:function=less,setpts=N/FR/TB" -vsync 0  outz.mp4`